# How to ensure that in twig if a content has no data it is not displayed

Tags: twig

In twig, I am outputting images. However, sometimes it is displayed as empty div with only spaces or even just empty. I tried to do the following such that when empty, the complete div is not displayed. However, it seemed to not display the div no matter whether  `{{ content.field_nova_panels_image }}` has image or not.

```
  {% if content.field_panels_image|trim is not empty %}
    <div class="col-md-3" style="max-width: 250px; padding: 0">
      {{ content.field_panels_image }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

If I have as below, I see the image there

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="max-width: 250px; padding: 0">
  {{ content.field_panels_image }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be other whitespace characters that `trim` isn't removing.

You can try a regex comparison for a string that contains only various whitespace characters:

```
{% if not content.field_panels_image matches '/^[\s]+$/' %}
```

Comment: @HelloUniverse, sorry I misread your question last night. I've updated my answer.